# Adnroid : TypeError: Network request failed] - react native

Tags: android, api, react-native, post, file-upload

**I have following code :**

```
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("image", {
      uri: this.state.photoUri, 
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      name: 'imageddd.jpeg',
    });

    await fetch('https://mysite/upload.php',{
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        "Accept" : "application/json"
      },
      body: formdata
      }).then(response => {
        console.log('response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

**but the problem i get**

> [TypeError: Network request failed]

in console

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the error is related to header, try removing header once, I mean try sending header object empty